# Pattern match interface for Java 8 showing compiler Warning

Tags: java, java-8, matching

I am building a command line tool that should validate some logic and if that fails it should print the error and exit, some of that logic could throw a runtime exception. I am using below java BiConsumer Interface.

```
BiConsumer<Consumer<T>,String> tryOrDie = 
    (block,msg)->
    {
        try
        {
            block.accept((T) this);
        }
        catch (Throwable t)
        {
            log.error(t.getMessage(), t);
            log.error(msg);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    };
```

So for example if my block would get other processes running this tool. This could be called like this to get other UNIX java processes with the name of this program (MyProgram)

```
final String currentPid=ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName();
currentPid=currentPid.substring(0,currentPid.indexOf("@"));    
String GET_ALERT_PID="ps -ef | grep MyProgram | grep -v grep | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2";
    tryOrDie.accept(y->{
                    otherPids = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Wrap.startProcess(GET_ALERT_PID))).lines().map(String::trim)
                            .filter(pid -> !pid.equalsIgnoreCase(currentPid))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
                }, "Could not determine if other running processIds of MyProgram were running");
```

The code works as expected, however I still get compiler warning 
***Type safety: Unchecked cast from MyProgram to T*** 
on line

```
block.accept((T) this);
```

Could this cause any memory leak or another issue? Is there any help to remove this type safety in the compiler? That would be helpful.

Comment: Type safety would hardly be a cause of memory leak to my knowledge. Just that the code is more prone to runtime failures than compile time. To ignore the warning, you can annotate with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` on the other hand, the cast can be justified by the actual source/meaning of `T` in the context.

Comment: `this` can not be safely cast to `T`, as it is impossible to prove that `this` is assignable to `T`. On the other hand, it’s not clear why you are using a `T` at this place at all. If the consumer should be capable of accepting your `this`, you should place the actual type of this into the declaration. Since your example use case doesn’t use that parameter at all, this would work without problems.

Comment: Holger, is good to see you so many years contributing for advising users on how to write more efficient java-8 code thanks for answering my post, I found the solution myself, changed declaration BiConsumer<Consumer<Object>,String> tryOrDie =  and block.accept(this); and that solved the compiler issues.